# Android App Bundle - Is it possible to have a pricing policy by features

Tags: android-app-bundle

About the new app publishing format ([App Bundle](https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle/)), it is said that:

> With Dynamic Delivery, users can download and install dynamic features when they’re needed.

But is it possible to set a price to one of those dynamic features and so not allowing everyone to download it? I do not see anything about pricing policy in the official documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic modules and in-app purchases are two distinct features that can be combined together, yes.

You can guard the code that downloads the feature (and also the one that executes it) behind the purchase of an in-app product.